# Angularjs get value from DynamoDB

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-4, angularjs-scope, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get value from DynamoDB then assign the value to ng-model to display the value. However, the data is always null.

```
Dynamodb table
 "meta_value": {
    "clause_note": "Note: good job!",
    "show_clause_note": true,
    "shown": true
  },
```

I'm getting the clause_note

```
Controller
            $scope.clause_note = null;
            $scope.item.remark = null;
            $scope.loading = true;
            $scope.getSettings = function () {
                customPrint.getAllSettings($scope.module).then(function (res) {
                    if ($scope.module) {
                        settings.then(function (stt) {
                            $scope.clause_note = stt['clause_note'];
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert('No module is specified!');
                    }
                }).finally(function () {
                    if ($scope.item.remark === $scope.clause_note) {
                        $scope.item.remark = '';
                        console.log($scope.clause_note);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $scope.clause_note = {show_clause_note: true};
                        $scope.clause_note = {shown: true};
                    }
                });
            };
            $scope.getSettings();
```

The console log returned as null.

```
html 
<ng-quill-editor ng-model="item.remark"></ng-quill-editor>
```

Comment: i think your data is in meta value object

Comment: Which mean I need a variable to get the meta value object?

Comment: no, you have to traverse on the object for the values on your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really enough information to answer this question. What is the value of the `stt` variable? If `meta_value` is a property on that object then this line:

`$scope.clause_note = stt['clause_note'];`

should be changed to

`$scope.clause_note = stt.meta_value.clause_note`

I'll edit this answer if you can let me know :)

But there are other problems with the code that make it harder to maintain.

For instance, it seems that `$scope.clause_note` can be a string or an object. That makes it harder to work with in other parts of the code because it's not always obvious what type it is.

The `settings` promise seems to come from nowhere. Maybe it would be a good idea to show where that comes from in your question. Also the response from `getAllSettings` is not used here. Is that a mistake?

Perhaps you should check if `$scope.module` exists before you even send the `getAllSettings` request. If it doesn't alert, and return. That should remove any branching logic inside your promise callbacks.

Comment: I got it, the stt is contained all of the objects and value. Therefore, I just use stt[object][value]; to get the value. Thanks for hint.